# how to declare variable name with "-" char (dash ) in linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote simple script as follow

```
#!/bin/bash

auth_type=""

SM_Read-only="Yes"
SM_write-only="No"

echo -e  ${SM_Read-only}
echo -e  ${SM_Write-only}

if [ "${SM_Read-only}" == "Yes" ] && [ "${SM_Write-only}" == "Yes" ] 
then
    auth_type="Read Write"
else
    auth_type="Read"
fi

echo -e $auth_type
```

And when i execute it i got following output with errors.

```
./script.bash: line 5: SM_Read-only=Yes: command not found
./script.bash: line 6: SM_write-only=No: command not found
only
only
Read
```

Any one know correct way to declare the variable with "-" (dash)?

**EDIT:**

have getting response from c code and evaluate the variables for example

```
RESP=`getValue SM_ Read-only ,Write-only 2>${ERR_DEV}`
RC=$?
eval "$RESP"
```

from above scripts code my c binary `getValue` know that script want `Read-only` and `Write-only` and return value to script.So during `eval $RESP` in cause error and in my script i access variable by

```
echo -e  ${SM_Read-only}
echo -e  ${SM_Write-only}
```

which also cause error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525424/how-to-declare-variable-name-with-char-dash-in-linux-bash-script

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rename the variable name as follows:

```
SM_Read_only="Yes"
SM_write_only="No"
```

Please, don't use `-` minus sign in variable names in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), please refer to the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23714), on how to set the proper variable name in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).

However if you generate the code, based on others output, you can simply process their output with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
RESP=$(getValue SM_ Read-rule,Write-rule 2>${ERR_DEV}|sed "s/-/_/g")
RC=$?
eval "$RESP"
```

Comment: ok that's true..but `-` char must require for me because word `Read-only` comes from in response of my c code and have just concatenate it with my bash string `SM_`. is there not any option to use it?

Comment: @jayeshbhoi you can fix it with `sed` like `echo SM_Read-only |sed "s/-/_/"`

Comment: ok.your alternative is very helpful but can you again see my edited question please.

Comment: Might want to perform a global find and replace with, `echo "my-string-here" | sed "s/-/_/g"`, otherwise not every `-` will be replaced. Note the difference here is the `g` at the end of the expression.

Comment: @Gewthen may be

Answer (score 5):

`-` is not allowed in shell variable names. Only letters, numbers, and underscore, and the first character must be a letter or underscore.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cant have a dash in your variables names, only letters, digits and "_"
Try:

> SM_Read_only

Or

> SM_ReadOnly